# Batch file moving to subfolders

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I have lots of folders including images in it. Example:

```
C:\U2090_08 
C:\U2111_08
C:\U2024_03 
C:\U2024_08 
C:\U2049_15
C:\U2049_35
```

There are 3-4 jpg files in every folder. I want to create a sub-folder called "kck" in every folder and move jpg files to this subfolder.

Example:

Before process:

```
C:\U2049_35\1.jpg
C:\U2049_35\2.jpg
C:\U2049_35\3.jpg
```

After process:

```
C:\U2049_35\kck\1.jpg
C:\U2049_35\kck\2.jpg
C:\U2049_35\kck\3.jpg
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
@echo off
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop

:: Sorting images in '\Desktop\images'
for /f "delims=" %%I in (' dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images\*.jpg" ') do (
    if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images\%%~nI\kck" ( md "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images\%%~nI\kck" )
    move "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images\%%~I" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images\%%~nI\kck\"
)
exit
```

Folders including jpg files in a folder called images on desktop.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: I tried file jugger software but it did not do the trick.

Comment: I mean code wise. This isn't a "give us a problem and we'll do all the work" site. Show us what you have tried with code and we'll assist you

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced Renamer software](http://www.advancedrenamer.com/) is able to do this. I have just tried it and it have very good move options. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Next code snippet could help:

```
@echo off
pushd "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images"

:: Sorting images in '\Desktop\images' (subfolders only)
for /f "delims=" %%I in (' dir /b /A:D ') do (
    if exist "%%~nxI\*.jpg" (
        md "%%~nxI\kck" 2>NUL
        move "%%~nxI\*.jpg" "%%~nxI\kck\"
    )
)
popd
exit
```

- all paths used in `dir`, `md` and `move` commands are relative to the current directory which is changed to `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\images"` via the `pushd` command;
- note `2>NUL`: redirected `STDERR` stream in the `md "%%~nxI\kck" 2>NUL` command instead of testing created folder existence explicitly by `if not exist "%%~nxI\kck\NUL" md "%%~nxI\kck"`.